# Are Gift items and other special items in Xenoverse 2 locked behind a PS Plus subscription?

Tags: psn, dragon-ball-xenoverse-2

Gift items in Xenoverse 2 are special items that can be bought from a merchant in the main city lobby of the game. It is my understanding that they shown up into the shop only when the player is playing online.

It is also my understanding that the game can't be played online without an active PS Plus subscription: the disclaimer you get in the game seems to indicate that only pvp, online PQ and other similar features should be inacessible, but I didn't see a way to even be able to access the city loby.

I am therefore trying to understand if I am missing some info or if some of the game content (gift foremost but also some items that apparently can be got only from online missions) is indeed locked behind having to pay for a PS Plus subscription.

Answer (score 2):

Not necessarily, the are some rare occasions where you can play online without a PS Plus subscription, like [last weekend](https://twitter.com/PlayStationEU/status/1470713694279639042):

> Dive into the online multiplayer modes of your favorite PS4 and PS5 games without a PlayStation Plus subscription during our Online Multiplayer Weekend from 18th December at 12:01AM – Dec 19 11:59PM local time.

Comment: ok, but in a way that is just Sony giving out a "free PS Plus Weekend". What I actually meant is if the (paid) online is the only way to get some items (that may also be locked to DLC you have to pay also).

Comment: @SPArcheon "It is my understanding that they shown up into the shop only when the player is playing online", this actually answers your own question. This is a common thing to have random drops/collectibles exclusive to online playing.

Comment: that's the whole point, I am asking if a) there is a way to go online without the PS+ pass like the disclaimer seem to imply (they say that without a PS+ subscription you can't take part in online PQ and such, but it looks like you should be able to access the lobby somehow?) or a way to get those offline

Comment: I doubt you can. Other sources state that multiplayer and online lobby are only for people with PS+ subscription, like [this](https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/boards/190457-dragon-ball-xenoverse-2/74793936).